# Stretch column table in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

How I can prevent to stretch table when I input long text:

Screen:
http://zapodaj.net/71821572f2445.jpg.html

Meyby is it possible to make the text lines stretched row horizontally?

My fragment example table:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" styleClass="table" value="#{userMB.allInactive}" var="inactive" paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{inactive.id}" selection="#{userMB.user}" selectionMode="single" >

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Lista kont nieaktywnych
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column headerText="#{msg.firstName}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{inactive.firstName}" />
                    </p:column>
```

I tried `<p:column headerText="#{msg.firstName}" width="20px">` 
styleClass for column: `<p:column styleClass="column" headerText="#{msg.firstName}" width="20px">`

```
.column {
    width: 20px;
}
```

but I do not see any change, it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show 2 line in one column in datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894919/how-to-show-2-line-in-one-column-in-datatable)

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution below.

[How to show 2 line in one column in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894919/how-to-show-2-line-in-one-column-in-datatable)

Comment: What version of primefaces are u using?

Comment: @Orange91 If you don't understand how to apply the solution just let me know. I will write you a sample.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is your friend, in your case:

```
overflow: hidden;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

You should set them on the element within the table cell. If you set `width`, the cell will be trimmed horizontally (no stretch, words will be break no matter of word length). If you set also `max-height`, the line will not stretch vertically above the limit you set.

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EuRZ/1/